# Opening web page hosted in azure , with ios web view asking Credentials inside web view

Tags: ios, swift, azure, adal

I am using ADAL 2.5.2 (for ios) version.After successful login, I am trying to open an URL in web view which is protected with Azure. But it is poping azure login inside web view initially. once we log in, then able to open how many no of times without login screen till we close the application.

If we open the application after some time again it will show the login screen in web view even though the access token still alive.
Maybe ADAL cache issue or unable figure out.

I am not passing bearer token to the web URL request.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I'm not very clear about your issue. Open web URL hosted in Azure? It means the  Azure AD application  or Web API?  Additional, If you want to access the Web API with the access token , you should use bearer tokens in HTTP requests.

Comment: I am accessing the web apis with bearer tokens. But I am opening a web report, is a page trying to open in web view which is showing the login page.

Comment: I assume that the issue may occurs  when web report cannot use the  token. You can use Fiddler to catch the traffic to find out the details. If you can post the details you catch, I believe we can find the cause.

Comment: Yes, web report is not using token. I tried to install FIdder on my mac. but there is an issue.  I will try and post the details

Comment: It is directly going to Aure login page.